# Get siblings of selected checkbox in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-selectors

here what I want to do is after selecting input checkbox B when I click on button A (delete) then I want to get all the siblings of selected checkboxes and find the delete button and check if that button is disabled or not.
what I tried was

```
$("body").on('click', '#deleteAll', function (e) {
  if ($("input:checkbox").is(':checked').siblings('.delete-website').is(':disabled')){
   $("#deleteAll").attr("disabled", true);
  }}
```

Thanks for your time

[image]

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: [is](https://api.jquery.com/is/) doesn't return a jquery object, so you can't chain `.siblings`

Comment: I would assume you need `filter()`, not `is()`

Comment: you mean `$("input:checkbox").filter(':checked').siblings('.delete-website').filter(':disabled')` ?

Comment: You can get parent node and then the children of the parent. Then remove/hide the children that are not current node. Sorry too complicated for me to write a JS code at this moment. There might be another simpler solution in jquery

Comment: No problem sir. I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
let dis = $('.someClass:checked')
  .map(function() {
    return $(this).closest('tr').find('.delete-website:disabled').length > 0
  })
  .get()
  .some(bool => bool)
console.log(dis)
$("#deleteAll").attr("disabled", dis)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="deleteAll">Delete all</label>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="someClass" checked></td>
    <td><button disabled class="delete-website">Trash</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="someClass"></td>
    <td><button class="delete-website">Trash</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="someClass"></td>
    <td><button disabled class="delete-website">Trash</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: kind of but here in the result here after clicking the (enabled button)  (deletes all) button should get enabled and all these things should happen after clicking the delete all button. Thanks tho. It can help little

Comment: can't i get siblings of checked chexboxes on click #deleteAll button ? is it possible ?

Comment: $('.someClass:checked')` are all checked checkboxes with the class someClass...

Comment: Fine. I got it.. it's working.. thanks... if($("input[name='delid[]']:checked").closest('tr').find('.delete-website').is(":disabled"));

Comment: I could have done that for you, had you posted HTML to begin with. :)